# jquery - adding listeners & performance

Tags: jquery, flip

I am playing with a jquery plugin called flip. I want to loop through a series of behaviors.  I am not if this is most efficient way to do this. I suspect that I am am adding a listener with each iteration which could affect performance.

ref: http://lab.smashup.it/flip/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        function myFunction(container, title,color){            
            var $this = $("#"+container);
            $this.flip({
                direction:'tb',
                content: title,
                color: color,
            })
        }

            var n=0;
            var doSomething = function(){                   
            if (n == 4) {n=1;} else {n++;}              

                switch(n)
            {
                case 1:
                myFunction("flipbox1","title1", "#1B9772");
                break;

                ...

                default:
                }
            }

            setInterval(doSomething, 1000); 

    });
```

Comment: "I suspect I am am adding a listener": what makes you think that?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: actually it is a function, but I notice that there is degradation in performance after a few minutes and browser is less responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't be worried about performance, something like this shouldn't be any big deal.  Callbacks are actually built into this jQuery plugin, so you need not write your own.  I'd try modifying your code slightly like such:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var title = "Hello!";
    var color = "orange";

    $("#myDiv").flip({
        direction:'tb',
        content: title,
        color: color,
        onBefore: function() {
            alert("Flip started");
        },
        onEnd: function() {
            alert("Flip ended");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: you are saying that I can use onEnd function instead of adding my own timer

Comment: Exactly!  Callbacks are built into this plugin, there's no need to write your own.  If my answer has helped you then mark it correct and upvote it so others can get help from it too.